# How to avoid users seeing code in a Google apps script library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm having troubles making my application runable but not viewable by my users and I'm looking for a description (/ recipe) telling me what to do in order to achieve what I want.

I wrote an UiApp using Google Apps Script and put this into a library (call it XXX here).
This UiApp uses Advanced Google Services drive api, drive sdk and calendar.
The calendar itself has been shared by all users.
The UiApp inside library XXX should only be useable by users that have been granted view access to the google drive.

I also wrote a small startup script (called YYY) calling library XXX.
Inside XXX I call library ZZZ containing the code for the UiApp.

YYY will run as a user, but ZZZ should be run as 'me'.

```
function doGet()
{ // Perform necessary actions before loading the UI from library ZZZ
   var info = null;
   var retVal = XXX.init(info); / Executing the UiApp inside library XXX

   Logger.log('XXX.init(info)= ' + retVal);
   return retVal;
}
```

Inside library XXX I have

```
function init(info)
{ // Starting UiApp inside library XXX after being called from outside the library
   return ZZZ.doGet(info);
}
```

and in YYY I define that library XXX can be used.

This worked with a previous version of my XXX-library.
Under Windows 7 I created a shortcut on the desktop to YYY and a user could start the UI by clicking on it without providing him edit access to the library.
Now I tried to activate a new library using the same settings while deploying the website and also activating the same Advanced Google services, but I can't get it working again.

So my questions are:
1) What settings should I use for XXX and YYY to make it possible that users don't see (the code of) libraries XXX and ZZZ, but are still able to run the UI inside it by running script YYY?

2) What procedure should be followed that allows me to put a new version of the library online without requiring the user to perform all kind of actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users need have view access to a library in order for them to use it, which means you can't prevent them from seeing the code. If you have private information in your code, store it in Script Properties instead, since those aren't visible to users with view access only.

Comment: It means users can copy and debug the code. Because of that they can see what will be retrieved from ScriptProperties too. So private data are not secure as well allthough it takes some effort. This leads to the question if code can be encrypted; loaded, decrypted and run at runtime in order to have some kind of security on the code and data. Apart from that : giving all the code isn't always intended nor desired. It also leads to the question 'what is Googles official point of v'iew of using Google Apps Script for security sensitive applications'

Comment: It's not possible for a read-only user to get access to script properties, unless your script already has a function around that logs the values. When a script it copied, the script properties are not copied with it.